# Easy way to convert the MS Access database to Web application

Tags: c#, asp.net, ms-access, sharepoint

As per requirement, we need to convert the existing MS Access database to a web application. Is there any easy way to convert the MS Access database to web application?  As of now they are inserting the data to access db using access Forms.  User also wish to continue access form feature even if we create new web application for the same. That means user should have the option to access the MS access database through Access forms as well as web application.

Please guide me away to solve this issue.

Best Regards,
Ranish

Comment: If by "convert the existing MS Access database to a web application" you mean access the data from a web application that you will develop, use the Access ODBC driver for that. If you expect to run some sort of wizard and have the Access forms functionality run on a browser... good luck with that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. As of now Access Db having Access Forms, where user can add/modify details to database.  we are looking an easy way to access   the MS access db content using web application.    we don’t wish to covert the Access db  to sql, since  user will continue to use the Access forms and these updates should access  through web application.

Comment: MS access = front-end + back-end: you need to split them so that both front-end and web front-end can access the MS ACCESS back-end. that's the basic you need to know.

Comment: Found this question because I have the same problem. And I have experience developing in both Access and ASP.Net (Webforms and MVC)... Pros and cons for every option. Just want to share a new approach that seems promising https://www.cybelesoft.com/blog/convert-access-web-app/?cn-reloaded=1

Answer (score 2):

You can use Office 365 and have somewhat of a web-based application.

https://blogs.office.com/en-us/2012/07/30/get-started-with-access-2013-web-apps/

Or, store Access in SharePoint, but your functionality will be quite limited.  Keep in mind, no VBA will run on a web-based application.

The alternative is to use SQL Server Express, and ASP.NET, both of which are free from Microsoft.  I'll tell you now, though, the learning curve will be quite steep if you have never used these technologies before.  This combo, however, will give you the most control!

You can get the .NET framework from here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30653

You can get SQL Server Express from here.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299

Answer (score 2):

Four years after and according to this:

https://www.comparitech.com/net-admin/microsoft-access/

still a question for many. Access can be converted to an Web App in almost no time. Particularly Access Forms are super easy to crate with the library like Jam.py.

The process was discussed on Reddit in April 2021:

https://www.reddit.com/r/MSAccess/comments/mj4aya/moving_ms_access_to_web/

I see quite a few Access databases with more than 100 tables, all converted successfully to SQLite3. After inspecting the imported tables via provided link, Forms are automatically created. Which leaves the Access Reports and Business Logic untouched. Reports can be designed in LibreOffice for Jam.py as Templates. Business Logic can be moved from VB to Python, if there is a need to do so.
The SQLite was selected as the default DB for the conversion, since it is very portable. Looks like the converted App can be moved to any DB that Jam.py supports, by Export/Import.
Cheers

Answer (score 1):

If you mean how to convert *automatically* and you want to keep both Access and the Web application (I don't recommend that, I would move everything to the Web app) I would do the following:

1. Export your Access data in CSV/Excel
2. Use a platform like [DaDaBIK](https://dadabik.com) to import the CSV/Excel file and automatically create a Web app based on that file, with data stored on SQL server, MySQL, PostgreSQL or SQLite.
3. connect your Access to the SQL Server (or Mysql, ...) database created by DaDaBIK, from now on Access will only be used as a frontend.

Now you have a web app created with DaDaBIK and your Access frontend both working on the same DB. As I said I would skip 3) and keep only the Web app, this helps with handling data integrity when two users are accessing the same record.

Depending on how complex is your Access Application (e.g. complex validation rules or custom VB code you added), you could reach your goal without any coding or with some coding.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, Database and Web Application are not mutually exclusive.

Back to original question, I have done multiple projects like that. A client started with small Microsoft Access database with a couple of user; then they migrate to to web application when they get more traffic.

At first, you want to convert data from MS Access Database to SQL Server. *MS Access Database is not meant to access multiple users simultaneously.* Then you develop the Web Application which uses SQL server as back end database.

Right before you go live, you convert the data again from MS Access Database to SQL Server very last time. Then do not let them use old MS Access Database anymore.

> Easy way to convert the MS Access database to Web application

Most of the time whoever created MS Access database are not software engineer, so table are not *normalized* and do not have *relationship* at all. I normally create new normalized database in SQL Server. Then write a small program to convert those data from MS Access to SQL database.

Comment: Thanks. At present, Access Db having Access Forms, where user can add/modify details to database. Also user not wish to convert the access db to sql,  since  user want to continue the Access forms and these updates should access  through web application. is there any easy way ? can I achieve it through share point?

Answer (score 0):

There are generally two approaches with more details covered in this article looking at ways to convert [microsoft access to web application](https://mindfieldconsulting.com/ways-to-convert-microsoft-access-to-web-application/)

**Direct Port** means simply a basic migration whereby you port more or less verbatim basic Access forms into a web portal i.e. Microsft Access to a browser-based version as is using a third-party tool. Some of these are quite mundane in that it just allows you to run the Access application inside an internet browser (whoopee!) or can be quite drawn out and then limits you on how much you can change afterward. With even more complex cases requiring a consultant to help you migrate the system. Though it does help to know your user count as the higher you tend to be, the less appealing a third-party porting service becomes due to subscription-based models.

**Upsize** -the more involved or complex your data structure is an upsize using custom development and splitting the system across web and data tiers might be worth it if

1. You've got a special process or some secret sauce you're looking to keep.
2. Likely going to have a significant user count and want to avoid subscription
3. Inherently cynical or cautious, and want to handle your own architecture and security
4. Looking for a specific user experience